# Tax rate java program

Tags: java, constants

I am new to java and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. After the user inputs annual income and # of exemptions, the code stops working. There are no error messages on my console either. Please help me.

The program:

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class TaxRate {

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
        // before asking the user for input


        final double TAX_RATE = 0.12;

        System.out.println ("Type in your name:"); 
        String name;
        name = sc.next(); 

        System.out.println (name + ", type in your annual income and number of exemptions, separated by spaces:"); 
        double  income, exempt;
        income = sc.nextDouble(); 
        exempt = sc.nextDouble();


        sc.close();
    } // main method 
} // lab class
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: After the user inputs annual income and # of exemptions, the code stops working. There are no error messages on my console either. @khelwood

Comment: What does "the code stops working mean"

Comment: after the user inputs what is asked of them (annual income and # of exemptions) there is no further activity in the console. what i want it to do is output: the adjusted gross income (the yearly income minus (2000 * #exemptions)) and tax which is 12% of annual income @Kon

Comment: none at all @PsyCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have

```
double num2 = 2000 * exempt;
num2 = sc.nextDouble();
```

you are calculating `num2` and then waiting for the user to enter it.

Where you have

```
double adjustedGrossIncome = income - num2;
adjustedGrossIncome = sc.nextDouble();
```

you are calculating `adjustedGrossIncome` and then waiting for the user to enter it.

Where you have

```
double tax = TAX_RATE * adjustedGrossIncome;
tax = sc.nextDouble();
```

you are calculating `tax` and then waiting for the user to enter it.

If you take out the `nextDouble()` lines in those three cases, your program will run along instead of stopping for user input.

Comment: I had gotten used to typing nextDouble() or nextInt() after declaring variables because most of the programs I'm creating are really interactive and need user input almost every step of the way. This was one of the first instances where I didn't need user input but out of habit I had included them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you ask for an input for tax that you already calculated, since that would be a useless line of code.

Comment: this is not an answer. :)

Comment: Is this your only problem? If so please accept this answer to close this question. And @kick buttpwski yeah it is :P

Comment: Fixed it and made it look more like a difinitive answer